# Create Android app in multiple languages

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-developer-api

I have submitted an Android app to Google Play and I see that I can create different descriptions for each language it supports. My question is: can I create a different APK for each language? Alternatively, how can I detect the user's preferred language, so that I can automatically activate that language for the user in the app?

Comment: there are different resource folders you can put in your project and the os chooses what to use based on the device so all you have to worry about is  what to display

Comment: [Refer official docs](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html) is the official tutorial for localizing your app. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a different apk for each language ( split-apk ) - but I would not recommend this. Better use the platform function for this and put your strings file in the right path ( values- ) - after this everything is automagically done

Answer (score 0):

no just use the /res/values/strings.xml
for example to choose english language create a folder in same directory of values and call it values-en, for frensh values-fr and so on. the default language of the app is under values/

Answer (score 0):

And if (for some reason) you still need to know witch is the devices language use

```
Locale.getDefault().getDisplayLanguage();
```